# How to set an Identity without logging in? No password + no database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I'd like to give people the opportunity to choose a username on my website. Just for their current session, without login, password,and database.

I was searching the web for answers, but I can't find a real answers. Maybe I just used the wrong terms.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Is [this what you are looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples)?

Comment: I don't think so. This doesn't to seem to work for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I believe you need to implement custom signing manager with in memory storage.
Something like here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Why do you need to set an identity? Why don't you store the preferred username in a session object or cookie?

Answer (score 2):

For setting current identity, you could try `HttpContext.SignInAsync`.

Follow steps below:

1. Controller

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           List<SelectListItem> select = new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem("Tom","Tom"),
               new SelectListItem("Jack","Jack"),
               new SelectListItem("Vicky","Vicky")
           };
           ViewBag.Select = select;
           return View();
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName)
       {
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
           var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
           var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
           await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
   }

   <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
       <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
       Hi @User?.Identity?.Name;
   </div>
   <form asp-action="Login" method="post">
       <select name="userName" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Select"></select>
       <input type="submit" value="Login" />
   </form>
   ```
3. Configure in `Startup.cs` to enable authentication

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
           {
               // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
               options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
               options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
           });

           services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddCookie();
           services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }
           else
           {
               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
               // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
           }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseStaticFiles();
           app.UseCookiePolicy();
           app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
       }
   }
   ```